# JavaScript function triggered by a clickable <div> tag to change image source of an <img> tag is not implementing

Tags: javascript, html, image

The JavaScript function to change the image source is not working.

This is my code:

```js
function eye() {
  fun();
  fun1();
}

function fun() {
  if (document.getElementById("password").type == "text") {
    document.getElementById("password").type = "password";
  } else if (document.getElementById("password").type == "password") {
    document.getElementById("password").type = "text";
  }
}

function fun1() {
  if (document.getElementById("eye").src == "eyec.png") {
    document.getElementById("eye").src = "eye.png";
  } else if (document.getElementById("eye").src == "eye.png") {
    document.getElementById("eye").src = "eyec.png";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <button class="menu_btn" onclick="start()">
                <img class="menu" src="menu.png" alt="menu" id="icon-menu">
            </button>
    <img class="logo" src="logo.png" alt="logo" />
    <header/>

    <form action="login-ctrl.php" method="post">
      <div class="log-form">
        <label for="email">Email:<br><input type="email" class="email"  placeholder="input email...." name="email"/></label><br>
        <label class="label" for="password">Password:<br><input type="password"   id="password" class="password" placeholder="input password...." name="password"/><div onclick="eye()" class="eye-btn"><img src="eye.png" id="eye"></div></label>
        <button class="log-but" type="submit" name="submit">login</button>
      </div>
    </form>

</body>
<script src="index.js"></script>
<script src="login.js"></script>

</html>
```

I have tried writing the functions in different scripts, but it still didn't work, it is supposed to change the source of the image to another when clicked first then back when clicked again.

Comment: Why do you call both `eye()` and `fun1()` from the "onclick" when `eye()` already calls `fun1()`?

Comment: `document.getElementById("eye").src` is `https://stacksnippets.net/eye.png` that's why your `if` doesn't work

Comment: `"Uncaught ReferenceError: start is not defined",` produced when this is ran here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read the parameter `document.getElementById("eye").src`, it returns the complete file path, like `file:///C:/Users/john/Documents/eye.png`. You can replace it with `getAttribute('src')` method:

```
function eye() {
  fun();
  fun1();
}

function fun() {
  if (document.getElementById("password").type == "text") {
    document.getElementById("password").type = "password";
  } else if (document.getElementById("password").type == "password") {
    document.getElementById("password").type = "text";
  }
}

function fun1() {
  if (document.getElementById("eye").getAttribute("src") == "eyec.png") {
    document.getElementById("eye").src = "eye.png";
  } else if (document.getElementById("eye").getAttribute("src") == "eye.png") {
    document.getElementById("eye").src = "eyec.png";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version that doesn't require all of the extra javascript, just a few lines of javascript and some CSS.

For this answer, I'm using javascript to detect the click and change the type.

From there, in CSS I'm changing the button's background based on type of .password. I changed the HTML so that the div is a button and it doesn't have an inline onclick nor an img tag in side.

In CSS, you can easily give the button different width/height and change the background to an image.

```js
let pw = document.querySelector("#password");
let eye = document.querySelector(".eye-btn");

eye.addEventListener("click",(e) => {
   pw.type = (pw.type == "password") ? "text" : "password";
});
```

```css
.eye-btn{
  width:15px;
  height:15px;
  outline:0;
  border:0;
 padding:0;margin:0;
}

.password[type='password'] ~ .eye-btn{
  background:green;
}

.password[type='text'] ~ .eye-btn{
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="password" id="password" class="password" placeholder="input password...." value="Text to see type change" name="password"/><button type="button" class="eye-btn"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet should do what you want. Even though we are not using jQuery, we should embrace its fundamental idea: "write less, do more!". This means: avoid using `id`s as CSS selectors and use class names instead. This way we can potentially apply a single function on many situations.

I also changed the event attachment of your click-event handler function `eye()` (now called `showHide`) - and the function itself - in some more ways, check it out below:

```js
function showHide(ev) {
  const img=ev.target, pw=img.closest(".eye-btn").previousElementSibling,
        hidden=pw.type==="password";
  pw.type=hidden?"text":"password";
  img.src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/"+(hidden?"c/cf/OOjs_UI_icon_eye.svg/20px-OOjs_UI_icon_eye.svg.png":"7/79/OOjs_UI_icon_eyeClosed.svg/20px-OOjs_UI_icon_eyeClosed.svg.png");
}
document.querySelectorAll(".eye-btn img").forEach(img=>img.addEventListener("click",showHide));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <button class="menu_btn" onclick="start()">
                <img class="menu" src="menu.png" alt="menu" id="icon-menu">
            </button>
    <img class="logo" src="logo.png" alt="logo" />
    <header/>

    <form action="login-ctrl.php" method="post">
      <div class="log-form">
        <label for="email">Email:<br><input type="email" class="email"  placeholder="input email...." name="email"/></label><br>
        <label class="label" for="password">Password:<br><input type="password"   id="password" class="password" placeholder="input password...." name="password"/><div class="eye-btn"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/79/OOjs_UI_icon_eyeClosed.svg/20px-OOjs_UI_icon_eyeClosed.svg.png"></div></label>
        <button class="log-but" type="submit" name="submit">login</button>
      </div>
    </form>

</body>
<script src="index.js"></script>
<script src="login.js"></script>

</html>
```

The "relative DOM navigation" from the clicked image `img` to the password input field `pw` might be noteworthy: `pw=img.closest(".eye-btn").previousElementSibling`. First I move up to the closest parent element being of class "eye-btn". From there I move back to the previous element sibling (this will skip any line breaks, spaces or other text nodes in between the elements).